# Conditionally apply Angular pipe on ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-pipe, angular2-custom-pipes

I have the following code:

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of users">
    <td>{{user.name}}</td>
    <td>{{user.surname}}</td>
    <td>{{user.age}}</td>
    <td>{{user.email}}</td>
    <td>{{user.username}}</td>
    <td>{{user.registrationDate}}</td>
</tr>
```

I need to apply a custom pipe to filter users that are not active.

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of users | filterBy: 'active'">
```

It works.

But I want to have pipe being applied conditionally, only if users click on given button.
I mean users press on "Show active only" and get list filtered by only active users.

Maybe I can't do that using pipe in HTML code, but I have to use it in the component, using pipe in the following way:

```
this.users = new FilterByPipe().transform(this.users, 'active');
```

Isn't this a dirty way since I should have a backup array to restore previous values?

Any better way?

Comment: Pass another parameter like `boolean` to your custom pipe and check if the param is true return active users otherwise return all users

Comment: Maybe you can conditionally render two `<tr>` elements one with **pipe** and and one without based on a value , say `showActive` in your TS ?